# Java - loading a binary tree from a text file

Tags: java, tree, stack

I'm attempting to load a binary tree from the corresponding string file.  I get a NoSuchElementException error pretty early on in the code(the exact line is commented), and I'm not sure that the algorithm will work to begin with.  The text file is ordered like this:

```
hello 0 0
my 0 0
name 1 1
```

where the first number indicates whether or not the node has a left child, and the second number indicates whether or not the node has a right child.

My BinaryTree class has two subclasses, ConsTree and EmptyTree, and each tree has its own left and right subtrees.

Here is the code for the method:

```
BinaryTree<String> loadFile(String filename)
{
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanny = new Scanner(file);

        Stack<BinaryTree<String>> stack = new Stack<BinaryTree<String>>();

        while(scanny.hasNextLine())
        {
            String data = scanny.next();
            int leftChild = scanny.nextInt();
            int rightChild = scanny.nextInt();
            ConsTree<String> tree = new ConsTree<String>(data, null, null);

            if(rightChild == 1) //this line throws a NoSuchElementException
            {
                tree.right = stack.pop();
            }

            if(leftChild == 1)
            {
                tree.left = stack.pop();
            }

            stack.push(tree);
        }

        return stack.pop();
}
```

Here are the constructors for my ConsTree class.  This is the only other code I had when I made the method.

```
public ConsTree(T data, BinaryTree<T> left, BinaryTree<T> right)
{
    this.data = data;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

public ConsTree(T data)
{
    this.left = new EmptyTree();
    this.right = new EmptyTree();
    this.data = data;
}
```

The constructor for the EmptyTree class is completely blank.

Here is what I'm using to test the method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
      Loader l = new Loader(); //the class with the load method in it
      BinaryTree<String> t = l.loadFile(args[0]);
      System.out.println(t);
 }
```

args[0] contains the name of the text file that has the contents listed towards the beginning of the question.

If anyone could put me in the right direction, that would be helpful.

If you need any other info, please let me know.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: So `hello` is a leaf node? also it's the `pop()` that is throwing the NoSuchElement. Not the `if` condition

Comment: yes, `hello` would be a leaf node.  If `hello` is just pushed on to the stack, why would trying to pop it off the stack throw an exception?

Comment: what is the exception? can you include the same also with the statck trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code with respect to reading the data elements and `if` conditions seems to be fine. **Error is not coming at this line** `if(rightChild == 1)`. Please look carefully, it must be coming from this line `tree.right = stack.pop();` or other line containing your stack operation.

I doubt its coming from `tree.right` as there is no element like this. If you can share rest of your code, it would be helpful in finding the exact issue.

Comment: Where is `Loader` and `BinaryTree`?

Comment: Loader is the class that contains the method that loads the file as well as the main method posted.  BinaryTree is an abstract class that just contains methods for EmptyTree and ConsTree.